# How to print list of list into one single list in python without using any for or while loop?

Tags: python, list, iteration

Today I had an interview and I was asked to print a list of list into one single list without using any for or while loop but you can use other built in function.

Here is the list:

```
>>> myList = [[[1,2,3],[4,5],[6,7,8,9]]]
>>> myList
[[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]]]
>>>
```

The output will be `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`.

Any idea how to go about this?

Comment: This is rare: *you can use other built in function* ;-)

Comment: +1, @AshwiniChaudhary. Also, I'm curious what will answer to this question give to an interviewer.

Comment: Hi Ashwini, which built in function.

Comment: related: [Flattening a shallow list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/406121/4279)

Comment: I would like to choose everyone answer as my solution but stackoverflow doesnt' allow me to do that :(

Comment: related: [Flatten (an irregular) list of lists in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2158395/4279)

Comment: @yopy, If I were you, I will vote for William Denman as an answer for the following reason: This is an interview Question, It is more appropriate to answer interview question without any particular library. Reduce is not a library but rather a primitive for functional programming. One has to think deep enough to understand how that works.

Comment: @Yeo, totally agree, I would love to see some more answer and i ll do as you  said.

Comment: @yopi, Let me further clarify what your interviewer means by no for or while loop. It means no iteration tools is allowed. That's what I interpret from the interviewer. 
If that's the case that means whoever answer with itertools library is disqualified.

Comment: Yes that was the requirement. So, itertool was not allowed, but sum and reduce is allowed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three options:

1. You could sum the nested lists; [`sum()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) takes a second argument, a starting value, set that to an empty list:

   ```
   >>> sum(myList[0], [])
   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
   ```

   This works because `sum()` is essentially implemented as a loop:

   ```
    def sum(values, start=0):
        total = start
        for value in values:
            total += value
        return total
   ```

   which works with list concatenation, provided the start value is a list object itself. `0 + [1, 2, 3]` would not work, but `[] + [1, 2, 3]` works just fine.
2. You could use [`reduce()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) with [`operator.add()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.add), which is essentially the same as `sum()`, minus the requirement to give a start value:

   ```
   from operator import add

   reduce(add, myList[0])
   ```

   `operator.add()` could be replaced with `lambda a, b: a + b` or with `list.__add__` if imports are to be avoided at all cost.

   As the nested input list grows, [`operator.iadd()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.add) (in-place add, for lists the equivalent of `list.extend()`) will rapidly become a faster option:

   ```
   from operator import iadd

   reduce(add, myList[0], [])
   ```

   but this *does* need an empty list to start with.
3. You could chain the lists using [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

   ```
   >>> from itertools import chain
   >>> list(chain.from_iterable(myList[0]))
   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
   ```

All three solutions require that you use indexing to remove the outermost list, although you can also pass the one element in `myList` as a single argument to `chain.from_iterable()` with `list(chain.from_iterable(*myList))` as well.

Of these options, `reduce(add, ...)` is the fastest:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("sum(myList[0], [])", 'from __main__ import myList')
1.2761731147766113
>>> timeit.timeit("reduce(add, myList[0])", 'from __main__ import myList; from operator import add')
1.0545191764831543
>>> timeit.timeit("reduce(lambda a, b: a.extend(b) or a, myList[0], [])", 'from __main__ import myList')
2.225532054901123
>>> timeit.timeit("list(chain.from_iterable(myList[0]))", 'from __main__ import myList; from itertools import chain')
2.0208170413970947
```

and comparing `iadd` versus `add`:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("reduce(add, myList[0])", 'from __main__ import myList; from operator import add')
0.9298770427703857
>>> timeit.timeit("reduce(iadd, myList[0], [])", 'from __main__ import myList; from operator import iadd')
1.178157091140747
>>> timeit.timeit("reduce(add, myListDoubled)", 'from __main__ import myList; myListDoubled = myList[0] + myList[0]; from operator import add')
2.3597090244293213
>>> timeit.timeit("reduce(iadd, myListDoubled, [])", 'from __main__ import myList; myListDoubled = myList[0] + myList[0]; from operator import iadd')
1.730151891708374
```

You could use recursion to avoid using a loop, to make this work for arbitrarily nested lists:

```
def flatten(lst):
    try:
        return flatten(sum(lst, []))
    except TypeError:
        return lst
```

Demo:

```
>>> flatten(myList)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> flatten(myList + myList)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: for exactly this list, for chain approach, one can use *myList instead of mylist[0]

Comment: Hi Martinjn,  could you please explain me how sum solve this from the help(sum) ,    sum(...)
    sum(sequence[, start]) -> value

    Returns the sum of a sequence of numbers (NOT strings) plus the value
    of parameter 'start' (which defaults to 0).  When the sequence is
    empty, returns start.

Comment: use `reduce(operator.iadd, lst[0], [])` to make it linear (`O(n)`-time) instead of quadratic (`O(n**2)`-time) algorithm. Initial value is provided to avoid changing `lst` inplace.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Oooh, good point. The alternative non-import version is then `lambda a, b: a.extend(b) or a`.

Comment: if imports are not allowed, you could use `list.__iadd__` instead of `operator.iadd`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: except that `reduce(operator.add, myList[0])` blows the socks of `reduce(operator.iadd, myList[0])`, speed wise.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: could you provide a script to try? How have you measured it (given that the code changes `myList` inplace)?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: the code does *not* change `myList` in place. Test with `timeit.timeit("reduce(iadd, myList[0], [])", 'from __main__ import myList; from operator import iadd')` versus `timeit.timeit("reduce(add, myList[0])", 'from __main__ import myList; from operator import add')`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: `add` gives me 1.0545191764831543, `iadd` 1.2767219543457031.

Comment: `reduce(operator.iadd, myList[0])` from [your comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20402558/how-to-print-list-of-list-into-one-single-list-in-python-without-using-any-for-o/20402688?noredirect=1#comment30484313_20402688) *does* change the list inplace. Are you really measuring the speed for `n==3`? Then you are measuring the difference between `reduce(a,b,c)` and `reduce(a,b)`. btw, it is 0.423ns vs. 0.559ns vs. 0.491ns for `(add,L)` vs. `(add, L, [])` vs. `(iadd, L, [])` where `ns` is nanoseconds.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Sorry, yes, that comment is incomplete. I did test with the additional start argument. Because `add` only requires two arguments to `reduce()`, and `iadd` requires three, that is the comparison you have to make.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: But indeed, `timeit.timeit("reduce(add, myList[0], [])", 'from __main__ import myList; from operator import add')`, so with additional third argument, is slower still, at 1.5228779315948486.

Comment: correction: it is obviously `microseconds` in the previous comment: us, not ns.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Try `>>> timeit.timeit("reduce(iadd, chain([], myList[0]))", 'from __main__ import myList; from operator import iadd; from itertools import chain')` next, it's competitive with `operator.add`; perhaps more so as more elements nested lists are added to `myList`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: it is misleading to talk about the fastest solution with a tiny input without explicitly mentioning it (sooner or later `O(n)` beats `O(n**2)` algorithm, it is already faster for `n==6` instead of `n==3` in this case).

Answer (score 4):

If we assume no imports allowed and that we are still on 2.7.x,

```
reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,*myList)
```

A quick search show that this question, making a flat list out of lists, has been analyzed in depth: [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python) and although in that thread there is no restriction on what functions you can use, they  answer goes into great detail about the time complexity of using different methods. This is quite important, as it could be the follow up question in an interview.

Comment: this is another awesome answer,

Comment: And Another assumption is running on Python2 Because in Python3 you need to import the [reduce function](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functools.html#functools.reduce)

Comment: @Yeo I didn't know that. Very good to know. Still on 2.7.x because of some scientific tools I am using.

Comment: @yopy, If I were you, I will vote this one as an answer for the following reason: This is an interview Question, It is more appropriate to answer this without any particular library. Reduce is not a library but rather a primitive functional programming. One has to think deep enough to understand how this works. :) +1

Comment: @Yeo gee thanks! Functional programming is indeed a strange, yet beautiful beast.

Answer (score 2):

```
myList = [[[1,2,3],[4,5],[6,7,8,9]]]

sum(myList[0], [])
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: wow this is what i want :) he was asking me to use sum :) i was thinking how to use to sum.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
In [34]: from itertools import chain

In [35]: list(chain.from_iterable(myList[0]))
Out[35]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: oh let me check this, without using module is there any other built in function to sove it.

Comment: @yopy Martijn and koffein answered that part.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
import itertools

list(itertools.chain(*mylist))
```